# ASUS laptop wi-fi hard blocked

Tags: networking, asus

I've been trying to make the wifi on my x450lc asus laptop to work, but so far I had no success.
I already try this fix from ubuntu forums: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558 but still got the wireless card hard blocked.
Before ubuntu I had windows installed and the wifi was working fine, and I already checked the BIOS to see if it was locked.

EDIT: So I managed to make the wifi work, I put the asus-wireless module on blacklist.conf and it seems to solve the problem

Comment: sorry for asking this stupid question but is the wifi indicator led on or off on your laptop?

Comment: my laptop doesn't have a physical led indicator, but the hotkey to enable/disable the wifi doesn't seem to work because the rfkill list still show the wifi card hard blocked

Comment: Hard blocked can be 3 things: BIOS, kernel module,  actual switch at the side or keyboard. BIOS blocked will disable the other 2. BIOS is a visit to BIOS. kernel module is a check of loaded and blacklisted modules. The 3rd is only active if the other 2 work.

Comment: Try holding the function key when you press the hotkey. If that's your problem, then you should go into your BIOS and change the default action of function keys to multimedia keys, or vice versa. If you were holding the function key, ignore everything else I've said and just hit the hotkey without holding anything.

Answer (score 0):

What type of error you're seeing?
if the problem was coming from Ubuntu then try to restart your network service by the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

if this didn't solve your problem then try the following solution:
1- go to your terminal and write
`cd /etc` Then press Enter
then write
`sudo nano resolv.conf` Then press Enter
A window will popup

```
#comment the line of nameserver 127.0.0.53(or any number) if it was found
# and write:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

## write it at the end. you'll see every thing at the end  by default

```
#then click ctrl + x to save , press y, press Enter
```

2- when you finish step 1 restart your network service by the following command:

sudo service network-manager restart

Comment: Actually I don't see any error, but I can't switch off the airplaine mode

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary fix on asus x52f

sudo ethtool -s ens5f5 speed 100 duplex full autoneg on

got me going at 100mbs

haven't restarted yet so we'll see what happens